# How to let a list append "nothing" (NOT NULL VALUE)

Tags: python

I have a function that will return different values depending on an if statement in the function. The returned value will be added to an existing list. However, in the function there is a case where I want the function to do nothing, i.e., the existing list will keep the same as if no function were called. Currently what I'm doing is the following, but I feel this looks messy and wondering if there is a better way to do:

```
import requests
def myfun(url):
    response=requests.get(url)
    code=response.status_code
    if code==503:
       time.sleep(3*random.random())
       value=None
    else:
       html=response.content()
       value=html['some tag']
    return (value,code)

lists=[]
for url in [my url pool]:
     (value,code)=myfun(url)
     lists.append(value)
     if code==503:
        lists.pop()
```

So basically what I do is to continuously visit some webpage, read some values then put the values in a growing list. However, sometime I get blocked (where Error Code 503 is given), then I want my code to sleep for a while then keep moving forward. In the case where  I get 503 error code, nothing will be returned so the growing list will be the same. But I don't know how to specify this case when I call the function, so I just set the returned values to None (or could be any value), then add them to the list but remove them from the list right after that. (So I use append() then pop() if the code is 503)

Comment: As I see you append to your list only in one place. Maybe consider to prevent appending to lists some values eg. using `if` clause. Always you can create a copy of your argument's list by `copy = list[:]` and if error occurs return this list instead of modified one.

Comment: Thank you Pipes. Are you suggesting that I implement the "append the list" task in the function? For example, current list will be an input, and a new list will be an output (if there is error, the output list will be the same, if else if will be a new one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `None` is used to indicate *no value*. It is the same as `NULL` in other languages.

In your scenario, the correct application would be to add `None` when 503 is returned.

Ideally, you should return `None` and whatever error code is returned - as I assume the remainder of your code should fail if say, a 500 error is raised instead.

Once you have looped through all the URLs, simply filter out the ones that were successful; this way you can later decide what you do with that data (for example, log them separately or queue them for another run, etc).

Here is an approach that doesn't discard "invalids", but simply filters them out:

```
def myfun(url):
    value = None
    response=requests.get(url)
    code=response.status_code
    if code > 400:
       time.sleep(3*random.random())
       return (value, code)
    else:
       html=response.content()
       value=html['some tag']
    return (value,code)

lists=[]

for url in [my url pool]:
     lists.append(myfun(url))

# you can also do    
lists = [myfun(url) for url in my_url_pool]

successful = filter(lists, key=lambda x: x[0] != None)
blocked = filter(lists, key=lambda x: x[0] == 503)
```

Comment: Thank you Burhan. Yes I guess you're write in the send I could get some error code other than 503, if that were the case then my code wouldn't be able to handle the error... Put all IDs associated errors in a list then pick out those with 503 and send requests afterwards sounds a great solution.

Comment: Another error code that I did get is 403, which seems to be the case that some web page does not exist anymore (for example, the code was suppose to visit a webpage of a chocolate product page, however the the request would be redirected to the homepage of that online store if the chocolate product has been removed from online store)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending the value, then checking for a 503 and removing the value...

```
lists.append(value)
if code==503:
   lists.pop()
```

Check that the response is *not* 503 and then append the value.

```
if code!=503:
   lists.append(value)
```

Comment: Thank you TigerhawkT3, following your way the code will look more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options; if you do care about the code, use the solution by @TigerhawkT3; if all you need is to append one value or none, you can e.g. just return `None` (and test for it), or return a (potentially empty) list, and `.extend` rather than `.append`

The latter option opens door to a particularly concise (while still readable) code:

```
import requests
def myfun(url):
    response=requests.get(url)
    code=response.status_code
    if code==503:
       ## why? time.sleep(3*random.random())
       return []
    else:
       html=response.content()
       return [html['some tag']]

lists=[value for url in [my url pool] for value in myfun(url)]
```

Comment: Thank you alf. But .extend may not work in my case because the returned "value" is actually a list, e.g., value=[123,'chocolate','out of stock']. Btw, in python is None equivalent to Null value?

Comment: The lovely thing about encapsulation is that you don't care about the details of the returned value: as long as you return a list of values, it is enough to know that the topmost structure is the list you want to `.extend`; whether its elements are lists, lists of lists, or anything else is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you alf~ Btw, the reason I'm doing time.sleep() when code 503 is raised is that most likely I'm blocked from the website at that moment so I'll let the code be "cool down" for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird case where I needed to append nothing, and I just used the increment operator

```
a += []
```